# How to merge each two columns from a data frame?

Tags: r

My data is like this

```
V2    V4       V6   V8
0     0.34     1    3
0.24    0      0.3  0
0       0      0    110
0       11     0    0
120     0      20   0
0       90     0    21
```

I want to have something like this with two condition, if in a row there are two values then get the average of them . if one value and one zero then put value and if both zero, then zero

so the output looks like this

```
V2      V6  
0.34    2   
0.24   0.3  
0      110
11      0   
120     20
90      21
```

I don't need to get the average because of many zeros we have and as said below will influence the results.

Comment: Are you doing the average of two columns?

Comment: you replace the zeros with NA and then use rowMean with na.rm=T

Comment: @akrun averaging could probably solve the problem, !!! because averaging zero will be that value !

Comment: Hmm, actually a zero affects the average... This is why your method doesn't make much sense. `0 != NA`

Comment: Eitherway, I think the correct way (IMO) is would be to take zeroes in count and do something like `(df[c(1, 3)] + df[c(2, 4)])/2`

Comment: @David Orenburg great listen David , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a `list` by subsetting the pair of adjacent two columns with the index generated using `seq`, `replace` the 0 with `NA`, get the `rowMeans`, do a second `replace` the `NaN` to 0.

```
m1 <- sapply(seq(1, ncol(df1), by=2), function(i) {
           x1 <- df1[ i:min((i+1), ncol(df1))]
           x2 <- rowMeans(replace(x1, x1==0, NA), na.rm=TRUE)
            replace(x2, is.nan(x2),0) 
 })
d1 <- as.data.frame(m1)
d1
#      V1    V2
#1   0.34   2.0
#2   0.24   0.3
#3   0.00 110.0
#4  11.00   0.0
#5 120.00  20.0
#6  90.00  21.0
```

Comment: if i put a data.frame at the begining would not change anything ? because i would like to have the output as data frame and not matrix

Comment: @Mol It is easier to convert a matrix to data.frame i..e `as.data.frame`